# How to receive my own Google Groups posts by e-mail?

Tags: google-groups, mailing-list

I'm setting up a Google Group for use as an open-source mailing-list.  In Mailman, as a user I can choose to receive copies of all messages by email (even ones that I send and ones that are cc:ed to me).  Can I do the same as a Google Groups user?  Being set to "Send me an email for every new message" doesn't seem to be enough.

Ditto for messages I approve as a moderator: the first one I approved, I did not receive by email, even it appeared in the group and I have received other e-mails from this group.

Comment: Could you explain your use case a little more? Why do you want to receive copies of your own messages?

Comment: For miscellaneous reasons that didn't fit in this margin so I blogged them: http://idupree.dreamwidth.org/3454.html